# How can I set up a click and collect type of shipping option where a customer collects their order from us

Tags: shipping

I want to offer people shopping on my Xpresso Store the option of collecting their order from our HQ. I call this 'Click and Collect'. So basically they select this option when checking out and no shipping costs are charged, instead they simply come and pick them up. Thank you

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're asking? Do you want someone to do this for you? This isn't a forum for hiring developers. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

it would be preferable if you look at the Documentation before asking. I don't know this extension, but on this page:

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/settings_shipping_methods.html

it seems clear that you can just create a shipping method with no shipping cost and title it "Click and Collect".

Comment: sorry for any confusion. *I want to be able to set it up myself not hire someone to do so. I just don't know how to set it up and hoped someone here could help me figure it out. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your original question, and delete this answer, since it's not an answer, just an addendum to your question.

Comment: I did look at this same page. I have created a shipping method with no costs and called it 'Click and Collect' but as it stands when someone puts something in their cart and goes to check out it does not offer any shipping options. It just applies the standard shipping that is already set up. It does not offer any other options. That page and all documentation I have been able to find offer no information about how to configure it to allow selection of other shipping methods. Thank you

Comment: If you're not a developer, I think you need to hire one. We need code examples from your templates to even approach helping you; hire a developer or hope someone here is willing away to give away their very valuable time.